# PS4 disc stuck and also not reading

Tags: ps4

I’ve tried taking it apart to see if there was any obvious problem but none that I could identify as I’m not an expert. My rainbow six disc got stuck in there the other day and my PlayStation said there wasn’t even a disc in it. I was able to take the disc out but now it doesn’t take nor read discs

Comment: Do you have kids? I heard from someone about a similar problem. When they took the disc drive apart, they found 3 discs jammed inside along with some bubble gum.

Comment: I have a little brother but he doesn’t have much reason to fiddle with it since his games are digital , the only hard copies I use are rainbow and gta very occasionally. But the disc drive didn’t have any  problems that I could identify

Answer (score 1):

> I was able to take the disc out but now it doesn’t take nor read discs

The disk was removed, but the internal disk loading mechanism was not reset manually. Because of this, the drive itself still thinks that there is a disk inside so it doesn't allows anything to be inserted.